# What is the best method of cutting out different "sections" out of a human body vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, pen-tool

I am designing an app in which patients can click on a part of their body they have injured.[image]

The image above is an old, raster image that I won't be using, but hopefully gives an idea of what I want to achieve. I'd like to divide the body into different sections. The developer will need the individual vector pieces of the body so that it can become highlighted when clicked.

What is the best method to do this within illustrator, especially taking into consideration that both sides of the body need to be symmetrical, and the developer needs each piece separtely in vector format?

I was thinking of using the pen tool to draw the shape I need, and then use the divide option. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to know the answer.. redraw half.. flip/copy... use divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Illustrator user, but Inkscape and other programs offer the same feature. According to [Adobe's help system](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/image-trace.html), it's called Image Trace in the Illustrator program:

> Choose Object > Image Trace > Make to trace with default parameters.
> Illustrator converts the image to black and white tracing result by
> default.

Results will vary based on the source image, but your image is just about perfect for this feature. The linked page has more detailed information, but I suspect the default settings will give you a suitable result.

In the "Edit the tracing result" portion of the above help link:

> When you are satisfied with the results of a tracing, you can convert
> the tracing object to paths. This final step allows you to work with
> the tracing result as you do other vector artwork. Once you convert
> the tracing object, you can no longer adjust the tracing options.
>
> ```
> Select the tracing result.
>
> To convert the tracing result to paths, do one of the following:
>     Click Expand in the Control panel or the Properties panel.
>     Choose Object > Image Trace > Expand. 
>
> The resulting paths are grouped together.
>
> To ungroup the grouped paths, click Ungroup in the Properties panel. Alternatively, choose Object > Ungroup.
>
> (Optional) To simplify paths by removing excess anchor points, choose Object > Path > Simplify. For details, see Simplify a path. 
>
> You can also reshape or edit paths. For details, see Adjust path segments.
>
> To color your tracing result, convert it to Live Paint Groups by selecting the desired paths and choosing Object > Live Paint > Make.
> ```
>
> For details, see Live Paint groups.

Comment: Yes, Illustrator's image trace will work for this. But then you need to Expand the trace to get vectors. It's also possible to trace in greyscale. [See example](https://imgur.com/IVCVLX1). Feel free to include this in your answer if you think it will help.